# Adding styles to child Components in Angular2-RC5

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have an angular2 app with an RC5 style submodule. The module is my tutorial module, with `tutorial.component` as it's root component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tutorial',
  template: `
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="col s9">
        <h1>Tutorial</h1>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app/tutorial/tutorial.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class tutorialComponent {
    public chapters = _chapters;
    clickedItem: number = 0;
 }
```

Here you can see the module routes:

```
const tutorialRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tutorial',
    component: tutorialComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'chapter/:id',  component: chapterComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'chapter/0', pathMatch: 'full'},
    ]
  }
];
```

So that's fine, however, in my child Component, `chapterComponent`, my css isn't being applied. Here is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chapter',
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css']
})
export class chapterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  private content: string = '';

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var id: string = params['id'];
      this.content = id;
      var that = this;
      var _url = './chapter/' + params['id'] + '.html';
      $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        success: function (result) {
          that.content = result;
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

But if I use the exact same path to the chapter.css file in my tutorial component, then the styles are applied.

Why are my child components behaving differently to parent components with respect to css application.